# When I add 0 to a number, the result is always zero. Other numbers are fine

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app that adds two numbers that I already wrote and show the result in the next activity. I got it to work with non zero numbers but when I add 0 to the other number, the result is always zero. I understand that it is because of the default value 0. but it is working fine with other values. When I add any number other than zero, it works fine, but when 0 is included, the whole result becomes zero. Please help me. Thank you!

MainActivity

```
package com.example.david.magic;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}

    public void no (View view){
        EditText editTextOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        EditText editTextTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(editTextOne.getText().toString());
        int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(editTextTwo.getText().toString());
        int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        // Now send the result sum to the Activity B through intent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("RESULT_SUM", sum);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    public void yes (View view){
        EditText editTextOned = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultno);
        EditText editTextTwod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int firstNumberd = Integer.parseInt(editTextOned.getText().toString());
        int secondNumberd = Integer.parseInt(editTextTwod.getText().toString());
        int sumd = firstNumberd + secondNumberd;
        // Now send the result sum to the Activity B through intent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("RESULT_SUMd", sumd);
        startActivity(intent);


    }}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.217"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.961"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:onClick="yes"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.739"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.961"
        android:text="No"
        android:onClick="no"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.381" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/resultno"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="104dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="0"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="128dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="366dp"
        android:layout_height="282dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/one"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.289" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main2Activity

```
package com.example.david.magic;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String fud;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        EditText hi = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            int sum = getIntent().getIntExtra("RESULT_SUM", 0);

            hi.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }


        EditText bye = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            int sumd = getIntent().getIntExtra("RESULT_SUMd", 0);

            bye.setText(String.valueOf(sumd));
        }
    }

    public void yyes (View view){
        EditText editTextOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        EditText editTextTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(editTextOne.getText().toString());
        int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(editTextTwo.getText().toString());
        int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        // Now send the result sum to the Activity B through intent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("RESULT_SUM1", sum);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    public void nno (View view){
        EditText editTextOne1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.saysno);
        EditText editTextTwo1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        int firstNumber1 = Integer.parseInt(editTextOne1.getText().toString());
        int secondNumber1 = Integer.parseInt(editTextTwo1.getText().toString());
        int sum2 = secondNumber1;
        // Now send the result sum to the Activity B through intent.
        Intent nno = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        nno.putExtra("RESULT_SUM2", sum2);
        startActivity(nno);


    }
}


activity_main2

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.217"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.961"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:onClick="yyes"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.739"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.961"
        android:text="No"
        android:onClick="nno"/>



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.381" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/saysno"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="196dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="196dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="366dp"
        android:layout_height="282dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.289" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Which EditText values are producing 0? I noticed textView2 is not assigned any value.

Comment: is the sum 0 when you hit only no button?

Comment: @maheryhaja yes. it is only 0 when i hit no button

Comment: @Ten textview2 is the sum. and resultno is the edittext with value of 0

Comment: and if i set default value to any number, when i hit no button, it turns to that number. But when i hit yes, it works just fine

Comment: @maheryhaja it seems like you know what is wrong since you knew only no button produces 0. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from this portion of code:

```
 EditText hi = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

        int sum = getIntent().getIntExtra("RESULT_SUM", 0);

        hi.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }


    EditText bye = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

        int sumd = getIntent().getIntExtra("RESULT_SUMd", 0);

        bye.setText(String.valueOf(sumd));
    }
```

Whatever you click yes or no, `extras` is not null. So when you click no, you got the righ value in the first `if`. But second `if` is always triggered. Since, you call setText for textView2 in both both case, `bye.setText(String.valueOf(sumd));` override the right value to 0 because "RESULT_SUMd" is null and 0 is default.

Let me explain inside the code with comment(case no):

```
EditText hi = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
//always true
if (extras != null) {
    // sum is set with right value
    int sum = getIntent().getIntExtra("RESULT_SUM", 0);

    //textView2 display the right sum
    hi.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
}


EditText bye = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

//always true
if (extras != null) {
    //no result_sumd found
    //sumd == 0
    int sumd = getIntent().getIntExtra("RESULT_SUMd", 0);

    //textView2 text is override with 0, value of sumd
    bye.setText(String.valueOf(sumd));
}
```

Of course, if you click yes, everything works because "RESULT_SUMd" is defined in that case.

So far, I suggest you to add another flag (to express where the intent come from yes/no) and add better if flow:

in first activity:

```
public void no (View view){
    EditText editTextOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    EditText editTextTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(editTextOne.getText().toString());
    int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(editTextTwo.getText().toString());
    int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    // Now send the result sum to the Activity B through intent.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("RESULT_SUM", sum);

    //add extra flag
    intent.putExtra("FROM_NO", true);
    startActivity(intent);


}

public void yes (View view){
    EditText editTextOned = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultno);
    EditText editTextTwod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    int firstNumberd = Integer.parseInt(editTextOned.getText().toString());
    int secondNumberd = Integer.parseInt(editTextTwod.getText().toString());
    int sumd = firstNumberd + secondNumberd;
    // Now send the result sum to the Activity B through intent.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("RESULT_SUMd", sumd);
    startActivity(intent);


}}
```

in the second activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    // hi is enough
    EditText hi = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        boolean fromNo = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("FROM_NO", false); 
        //use of ternary to make it simple
        int sum = getIntent().getIntExtra(fromNo?"RESULT_SUM":"RESULT_SUMd", 0);
        hi.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }

 }
```

Comment: the result is now 0 for both yes and no

Comment: it's a pleasure ;)

Comment: i finished the app

Comment: Wow :D want to see your app

Comment: not sure if youre joking but here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hzNMre-4bvr0iIw5tc0JPIK5L9w872Rd/view

Answer (score 0):

FirstActivity.java file

```
EditText e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);`
int num1=Integer.parseInt(e.getText().toString());
int num2=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
int sum=num1+num2;
Intent in=new Intent(this,SecondSplash.class);
in.putExtra("value",sum);
startActivity(in);
```

SecondActivity.java file

```
TextView txtView;
String value;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_splash);

    Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b!=null)
    {
        value=b.getString("value");
    }
    txtView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //value=getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");
    txtView.setText(value);
```

Comment: the value is nothing